# i am trying to get value from javascript to jsp using hidden field but how to know that i am getting the value on the same jsp page

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

```
<html> 
<script>
function brnch()
{
var client_code = document.getElementById("cname").value;
xmlobj=ajaxFunction();
xmlobj.onreadystatechange=function(){
if(xmlobj.readyState == 4)
{
var resp = xmlobj.responseText;
document.getElementById("brch").value=resp;
}
}
var url="getbranch.jsp?c_code="+client_code;
xmlobj.open("POST",url,true);
xmlobj.send();
}
</script>
<input type="hidden" name="brancht" id="brch" value="">
<%
String value=request.getParameter("brch");
System.out.println("hidden field :"+value);
%>
</html>
```

i am trying to get value from javascript to jsp using hidden field but how 
    to know that i am getting the value on the same jsp page.

Answer (score 0):

To check you got parameter value or not, you can compare with `null` value as below.

```
if(Request.getParameter("brch")!=null)
{
     ...
     ...
}
```